# events on arrayproxy emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So I have an object of ArrayProxy kind

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();
App.car = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
  content:customers,
  edit:function(e){
    alert(e);
  }
});
```

on my template I have an anchor tag with the action edit on click set to it by handle bars

```
<a class="primary action" {{action "edit" on="click"}}>Edit</a>
```

this isn't working and I think its because I can't set events on ArrayProxys... either that or something else?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a target to your `action` helper:

```
<a class="primary action" {{action "edit" target="App.car"}}>Edit</a>
```

And `click` is the default event, so you could remove the `on` ...